# Remove eclipse on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, eclipse

Does anyone know how to uninstall Ubuntu eclipse? I downloaded the `tar.gz` file from their official website and installed it and all went good, the problem is I want to uninstall the top bar because I get the name of a project to clear and open it whenever I get the same thing, it is not something that affects the program but I find it uncomfortable, it is noteworthy that is installed in the /usr/share.

I want remove text from the top bar, so that only appears the name "eclipse"

Comment: What do you want to uninstall? Eclipse or a mysterious top bar?

Comment: I want remove text from the top bar, so that only appears the name "eclipse"

Comment: Do you mean the window title bar of eclipse?

Comment: Yes, the title bar.

Answer (score 0):

**Based on your comments:**

Bad news my friend. You can add and/or remove the workspace name and the name of the perspective in the title bar. But you can't remove the other entries.

And this trick only works until the title of Eclipse itself is changed again:

```
wmctrl -l | awk '/Java.*Eclipse/ {print $1}'  | xargs -I {} wmctrl -i -r {} -T "Eclipse"
```

The command searches the Eclipse window and changing its title.

And this is a really dirty hack:

```
#!/bin/bash
/<your_eclipse_path>/eclipse &

# Wait for eclipse
sleep 15

WIN=$(wmctrl -l | awk '/Java.*Eclipse/ {print $1}')
echo "$WIN"
while [[ "$WIN" != "" ]]; do 
  sleep 1
  wmctrl -i -r "$WIN" -T "Eclipse"
  WIN=$(wmctrl -l | grep -o "$WIN")
done
```